# What is the purpose of entity_keys in ContentEntityBase?

Tags: entities, 8

I'm trying to figure out what is the purpose of `entity_keys` in `ContentEntityBase` entities and what fields should be set as `entity_keys`.

For example in [\Drupal\node\Entity\Node](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Entity%21Node.php/class/Node/8) we have such entity_keys:

```
entity_keys = {
 "id" = "nid",
 "revision" = "vid",
 "bundle" = "type",
 "label" = "title",
 "langcode" = "langcode",
 "uuid" = "uuid",
 "status" = "status",
 "uid" = "uid",
}
```

Why exactly these fields are selected to be `entity_keys`? And, for example, why in [\Drupal\comment\Entity\Comment](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21comment%21src%21Entity%21Comment.php/class/Comment/8) `status` isn't in `entity_keys`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

entity_keys are basically an alias for fields. It allows generic code, like the storage backends, to access common fields that have different names, for example the ID. They need write the saved value, so the can't just use id() as most places.

Internally, those keys are also used by generic methods like id(), label(), getRevisionId() and so on, so they work out of the box.

There isn't really a reason that comment doesn't define status. Nothing really uses status, if you search for getKey('status'), there are no matches, while getKey('id') finds a lot.

Node only uses it internally for the isPublished().

Comment: Maybe important to point out: The annotation has "entity_keys" with entries like "id" = "nid". The entity has a property $entity->entityKeys with entries like ['id' => 5]. So this property holds the values of those keys, not the keys themselves.

Comment: So If I guess correctly If we dont add them for some fields they can be just accessed/used as defaults?